# Saving content of property 'text' of my instance of a textbox - How to join all strings - C#

Tags: c#, string

I have an xml schema that is not separated into the <> format, is just the schema in a textbox where there is no separation between the <> and the following one .

Example:

`<Cmp><Id>"Value"</Id><fecha_cbte>"Value"</fecha_cbte><Tipo_cbte>"Value"</Tipo_cbte><Punto_vta>"Value"</Punto_vta><Cbte_nro>"Value"</Cbte_nro><Tipo_expo>"Value"</Tipo_expo><Permiso_existente>"Value"</Permiso_existe>`

And so on. So you can see everything is "joined", there is no separation.

The idea is to join everything as a single and long char, after that my dea is to use a

```
for (int i=0; i < myVariable.Count; i++)
{
   if (myVariable == ">" && myVariable == "<")
   {
    //Here I can split the string with /n everytime it finds a > and <
   }
}
```

So at the end it should be something like:

`<Cmp>
<Id>
"Value"
</Id>
<fecha_cbte>
"Value"
</fecha_cbte>
<Tipo_cbte>
"Value"`

etc...

So I can separate the '<' '>' from the numeric value.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Best Regards!

Comment: So, basically, you're trying to indent XML ?

Comment: Exactly, the problem is, I dont have an XML document, they just give me the schema like that with no identation whatsoever.

Comment: I made some changes to your code. 1. It's all wrong, for example, `if`'s don't have capitalization, the `i` declaration should be inside the `for-loop`, it's `.Count` in C#, not `.lenght`, and it should be `<` not `<=`, which will cause an error, and the naming convention is not C#'s naming conventions.

Comment: Your example looks like a valid XML document !

Comment: Thanks theGreenCabbage!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<Cmp><Id>Value</Id><fecha_cbte >Value</fecha_cbte><Tipo_cbte>Value</Tip o_cbte></Cmp>");
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("c:\\temp\\nicexml.xml",null))
{
  writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: This could be it and if it is, is elegant, precise and short.
Let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "<Cmp><Id>\"Value\"</Id><fecha_cbte>\"Value\"</fecha_cbte><Tipo_cbte>\"Value\"</Tipo_cbte><Punto_vta>\"Value\"</Punto_vta><Cbte_nro>\"Value\"</Cbte_nro><Tipo_expo>\"Value\"</Tipo_expo><Permiso_existente>\"Value\"</Permiso_existe>";
string result = str.Replace("<", "\r\n<").Replace(">", ">\r\n").Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
```

So assume each `<` starts a line - add CRLF before, assume each `>` ends a line, add CRLF after it. Final bit gets rid of any empty lines inserted.

Comment: **however** I can't help but feel we are fixing the wrong problem. What are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
    string s = "this is a string";
// Split string on spaces.

string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: do you understand the question ?

Comment: I think so, wants to split a string ?

Comment: No, he has a xml content and wants to add line break between elements.

Comment: dont thinks that's valid XML, just has some data in a textbox according to the OP, so it becomes a string ?

Comment: is just the schema in a textbox (see question)